# java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class ReadUpdateDb {

    public void updateDb(Statement stmt) {
        try {
            ArrayList<String> inner = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            ResultSet up = null;
            ResultSet mp = null;
            //up = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT application_no FROM ng_lms_rsystems_interface");
            //rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ng_lms_rsystems_interface");
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT application_no,ucic_id,validation_flag FROM ng_lms_rsystems_interface");
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            while (rs.next()) {
                inner = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++) {
                    inner.add(rs.getString(i));
                    String p = rs.getString(i);
                    if (p == null) {
                        System.out.println(p);
                        up = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT application_no FROM ng_lms_rsystems_interface");
                        ReadUpdateDb c = new ReadUpdateDb();
                        long rc = c.update();
                        System.out.println("done4");
                        String updt = c.getApplicationNo(up);
                        System.out.println("done7");
                        mp = stmt.executeQuery("UPDATE ng_lms_rsystems_interface SET ucic_id = '" + rc + "', validation_flag = 'Y' WHERE APPLICATION_NO = " + updt + "");
                    }
                }

                // outer.add(inner);
                    /*int n = (rs).getInt(1);
                    String p = rs.getString(2);
                    String q = rs.getString(3);
                    System.out.println(n+"    "+p+"   "+q);
                    }*/
                //for(String obj:inner) { 
                //  System.out.println(obj);
                //}
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Below method gets the application number from database which i need to use in the update query:

```
public String getApplicationNo(ResultSet up) throws SQLException {
    System.out.println("done1");
    ArrayList<String> inner = null; 
    String n = null;
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = up.getMetaData();
    int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    while(up.next()) {
        inner = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        for(int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++){
        inner.add(up.getString(i));        
        //String p = up.getString(i);
    }
    //inner = new ArrayList<String>();
    //System.out.println("done2");
    //inner.add(up.getString(1));   
    //System.out.println("done3");
    int count = 0;
    //String n = up.getString(1);

    for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        n = inner.get(i);
    }

    System.out.println("done");
    return n;   
}
```

Below method gives id which is to be updated:

```
public long update() {
    long t1 = 4466880011L;
    System.out.println("done9");
    return t1;
}
```

Code here I have written above code to read and update database but when I run the code I get this result set exhausted error I tried to solve this but no success.

Comment: Which line is causing the exception?

Comment: getApplicationNo methods has some problem in it but I couldn't find it

Comment: You generally can't retrieve the same column twice. Store it into a variable.

Comment: Is this the exact code that's raising the exception? First, the braces following the while loop do not match up with those after the enclosed for loop. I suspect you edited the code for display. Commented lines (`inner.add(up.getString(1));`) could have caused the exception to be raised, esp.with your current block/braces... nothing apparent in the code as is.

Comment: @EJP Most drivers have no problems with that (afaik only the JdbcOdbcDriver has quirks here).

Answer (score 1):

You execute another query on `stmt` while iterating over a result set produced by `stmt`. As soon as you execute another query on the same statement object, any previous result sets created by that statement  object are closed. So when you try use `getString` afterwards you get this error.

To fix this you need to use another statement object inside the loop (and make sure you have disabled auto-commit).

Also note that your current way of executing statements is unsafe: you are concatenating values into a query string. That leaves you open to SQL injection, instead you should use a prepared statement with parameters.

Comment: inner.add(rs.getString(i)); at this line exception is thrown

Comment: Yes, and that line is in a loop (twice), so on the second iteration of either loop, the result set will be closed.

Comment: See the second paragraph.